# Parsing spanish text and saving it in a db

Tags: python, parsing, unicode

I'm parsing a web page written in spanish with [scrapy](http://scrapy.org). The problem is that I can't save the text because of the wrong encoding.

This is the parse function:

```
def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        text = hxs.select('//text()').extract() # Ex: [u' Sustancia mineral, m\xe1s o menos dura y compacta, que no es terrosa ni de aspecto met\xe1lico.']
        s = "".join(text)
        db = dbf.Dbf("test.dbf", new=True)
        db.addField(
            ("WORD", "C", 25),
            ("DATA", "M", 15000), # Memo field
        )
        rec = db.newRecord()
        rec["WORD"] = "Stone"
        rec["DATA"] = s
        rec.store()
        db.close()
```

When I try to save it to a db(a dbf db) I get an ASCII(128) error. I tried decoding/encoding using 'utf-8' and 'latin1' but with no success.

Edit:

To save the db I'm using [dbfpy](http://www.fiby.at/dbfpy/). I added the dbf saving code in the parse function above.

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1179, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 778, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 280, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 354, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 371, in _runCallbacks
    self.result = callback(self.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/katy/Dropbox/proyectos/rae/rae/spiders/rae_spider.py", line 54, in parse
    rec.store()
  File "/home/katy/Dropbox/proyectos/rae/rae/spiders/record.py", line 211, in store
    self.dbf.append(self)
  File "/home/katy/Dropbox/proyectos/rae/rae/spiders/dbf.py", line 214, in append
    record._write()
  File "/home/katy/Dropbox/proyectos/rae/rae/spiders/record.py", line 173, in _write
    self.dbf.stream.write(self.toString())
  File "/home/katy/Dropbox/proyectos/rae/rae/spiders/record.py", line 223, in toString
    for (_def, _dat) in izip(self.dbf.header.fields, self.fieldData)
  File "/home/katy/Dropbox/proyectos/rae/rae/spiders/fields.py", line 215, in encodeValue
    return str(value)[:self.length].ljust(self.length)
exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error you see, along with the code that causes it?

Comment: So you get unicode from your web page. That's nice, just as it should be. That is not your problem. Your problem is "saving it as a dbf db" -- you need to show the code that tries to do that; we don't have crystal balls. You will need to give us a link to the dbf-handling module that you are using.

Comment: Also please confirm that you mean a DBF file as used by dBase III etc and Visual Foxpro -- if not, what is it?

Comment: Yeah John, the dbf is going to be used in Visual Foxpro.

Comment: The link that you gave is to an outdated module, not the one that you are using. Please try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, don't remember that [DBF files don't support unicode at all](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/129631) 
and I also suggest to use Ethan Furman's dbf package (link in another answer)

You can use only 'table = dbf.Table('filename') to guess real type.

Example of usage with non cp437 encoding is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: koi8-r
import dbf
text = 'текст в koi8-r'
table = dbf.Table(':memory:', ['test M'], 128, False, False, True, False, 'dbf', 'koi8-r')
record = table.append()
record.test = text
```

**Please note following information about version 0.87.14 and 'dbf' table type:**

---

With DBF package 0.87.14 you can found exception 'TypeError: ord() excepted character...' at ".../site-packages/dbf/tables.py", line 686

Only 'dbf' table type has affected with this tupo!

**DISCLAIMER**: I don't know real correct values to use in following values, so don't blame me about incompatibility with this "fix".

You can to replace values '' to '\0' (at least) at lines 490 and 491 to make this test workable.

Comment: The latest code for my dbf package can by found on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf), and an easier way to create the table in the example above would be `table = dbf.Table(':memory', 'test M', dbf_type='vfp', codepage='koi8-r')`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbfpy is what you are talking about. Whatever gave you the idea that it could handle creating a VFP-compatible DBF file just by throwing Unicode at it? There's no docs worth the description AFAICT and the source simply doesn't contain `.encode(` and there's no supported way of changing the default "signature" away from 0x03 (very plain dBaseIII dile)/

If you encode your text fields in `cp850` or `cp437` before you throw them at the dbf it may work, but you'll need to check that you can open the resulting file using VFP and that all your accented Spanish characters are represented properly when you view the text fields on the screen.

If that doesn't work (and even if it does), you should have a look at [Ethan Furman's dbf package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) ... it purports to know all about VFP and language driver IDs and codepages and suchlike.

**Update:** I see that you have 15000-byte memo field defined. One of us is missing something ... the code that I'm reading says in `fields.py` about line 330 `Note: memos aren't currenly [sic] completely supported` followed a bit later by two occurrences of `raise NotImplementedError` ... back up to line 3: `TODO: - make memos work`. When I tried the code that you say you used (with plain ASCII data), it raised NotImplementedError from the `rec.store()`. Have you managed to get it to work at all?

Comment: Thanks for your response John. I'll give a look at the package you mentioned. The library worked well with some demo data. I know that memos aren't fully supported, I tried changing the field to character and it raised the same error.

Comment: @mfalcon: memos aren't supported AT ALL (unless you call raising NotImplementedError "partial support"), and that's a second problem on top of your encoding problem.